Conveying "procrastination" in Japanese
A concept in conversations I've wanted to say but have struggled to figure out the best way is to convey that I have "procrastinated" some task or that I tend to procrastinate stuff.
The issue is all the associated Japanese words seem not to be what I am looking for:
►回答を先延ばしにする　put off a reply until later; postpone [delay] replying.
->先延ばし seems to focus on delaying some task, but it seems more often used for putting off replies/decisions rather than say, "I procrastinated my homework".
医師の怠慢によって助かる命が助からなかった.
->Negligence seems to fit 怠慢 better than "procrastination" because it is it used in more negative, possibly more serious contexts.
勉強を怠ける　neglect [be inattentive to, be lazy in] one's studies
->While I see this word used for studies and work, I feel like it emphasizes the laziness and neglect aspect more than English "procrastination".
While I know there is probably no 1-1 translation, my idea of procrastination isn't merely putting off a task but also includes the fact that you know there are negative consequences for putting off your task but neglect it anyway. I have also read threads including natives who give examples but I don't feel like this nuance was emphasized. Perhaps this nuance is also present in one of these (or other) words, but I could not find anything that confirmed it.

放っておく(often ほっとく in informal speech) might be close if you don't need to retain the formality of "procrastinate."

As the answer suggests, 先延ばし implies gilt of putting off, depending on what is postponed. But it can only be used as a transitive verb.

Actually, I think 先延ばし is a good choice here. It can safely be used for tasks, homeworks, etc.

The general meaning of 先延ばし to postpone, but 明鏡国語辞典 goes a little further and defines as


すぐにすべきことや予定されていたことを先に伸ばすこと。先送り。 (emphasis by me)


The tendency to 先延ばし, for example of the homework for summer vacation (longest school break in Japan), is often discussed:

Essay on「夏休みの宿題は前倒し派? 先延ばし派?」 on 家電 Watch


Many scientific articles on 先延ばし in educational settings can be identified: for example on jstage.

先送り can be used similarly (e.g. radio episode on 宿題、課題、ダイエット……。先送りしないためには!?, also depending on context, 後回し (e.g. essay on 後回し癖を解消する方法 on Shimadzu).

For 怠慢 and 怠ける, I think your understanding is correct.

I agree negligence fits 怠慢 better. Also 怠慢 does not necessarily mean they postponed something out of laziness: the negligence can be caused by, for example, lack of appropriate attention.
怠ける puts emphasis on laziness.

